# Break statement cannot break the nested loop in Oracle Apex

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex

I tried to jump out of the outer loop when a certain condition is met. So I labeled each loop and use break statement to specify which loop I want to break but it didn't work. Below are my codes, the console.log statement inside the else block still print 1 to the console even though break statement executed. What did I do wrong in the javascript codes?

HTML for table:

```
<table class="t-Report-report ui-sortable" id="seq_report">
        <thead>
            <tr class="ui-sortable-handle">
                <th class="t-Report-colHead" align="left" id="PK_DISPLAY">&nbsp;</th>
                <th class="t-Report-colHead" align="center" id="POS_NBR">Position</th>
                <th class="t-Report-colHead" align="center" id="DISP_VAL">Description</th>
                <th class="t-Report-colHead" align="center" id="SEQ_NBR">Seq</th>
                <th class="t-Report-colHead" align="center" id="PERM"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr data-id="19691" class="ui-sortable-handle">
                <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="PK_DISPLAY"><a href="#" data-id="19691"></a></td>
                <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="POS_NBR">05M</td>
                <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="DISP_VAL">t05</td>
                <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="SEQ_NBR">1</td>
                <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="PERM">Perm</td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-id="19692" class="ui-sortable-handle">
                <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="PK_DISPLAY"><a href="#" data-id="19692"></a></td>
                <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="POS_NBR">06M</td>
                <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="DISP_VAL">t06</td>
                <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="SEQ_NBR">2</td>
                <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="PERM">Perm</td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-id="19690" class="ui-sortable-handle">
                <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="PK_DISPLAY"><a href="#" data-id="19690"></a></td>
                <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="POS_NBR">04M</td>
                <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="DISP_VAL">t04</td>
                <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="SEQ_NBR">3</td>
                <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="PERM">Perm</td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-id="19687" class="ui-sortable-handle">
                <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="PK_DISPLAY"><a href="#" data-id="19687"></a></td>
                <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="POS_NBR">04M</td>
                <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="DISP_VAL">t04</td>
                <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="SEQ_NBR">4</td>
                <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="PERM">Temp</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Javascript:

```
function makeSortable(pRegionID) {
    var $r = $("#report_" + pRegionID);
    var r = $r[0];// add ID to TR element so we know the correct position
    var $perm;
    var $obj;
    

    $r.find("[headers='PK_DISPLAY'] a").each(function () {
        //console.log($(this));
        $(this).parent().parent().attr('data-id', $(this).data("id"));
        // $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-id',$(this).data("id"));

    });// finally make it sortable

    $r.find("table.t-Report-report").sortable({
        items: 'tr'
        , containment: r
        , helper: fixHelper
        , update: function (event, ui) {
            var found = 0;
            
            $obj = $r.find("[headers='POS_NBR']");
            $perm = $obj.next().next().next();
            
            
            loop1:for (var i = 0; i < $obj.length - 1; i++) {

                loop2:for (var j = 0; j < $obj.length - 1 - i; j++) {
                    if ($obj[i].innerHTML == $obj[i + 1 + j].innerHTML && $perm[i].innerHTML == 'Temp') {    
                        apex.message.alert("Go out");
                        apex.event.trigger($r, 'apexrefresh');
                       
                        break loop1;
                    }else{  
                        console.log(1);
                        updateDisplaySeq(r);                       
                    }
                }
               
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`break` will only break the current loop where it is.

But! You can be creative and wisely use another variable, just to also break the outer loop.
Look at the `finish` variable below...

```
var finish = false
for (var i = 0; i < $obj.length - 1; i++) {

    for (var j = 0; j < $obj.length - 1 - i; j++) {
        if ($obj[i].innerHTML == $obj[i + 1 + j].innerHTML && $perm[i].innerHTML == 'Temp') {    
            apex.message.alert("Go out");
            apex.event.trigger($r, 'apexrefresh');
            
            finish = true
            break;
        }else{  
            console.log(1);
            updateDisplaySeq(r);                       
        }
    }
    if(finish){
        break;
    }
}
```